# Building Mobile Sites with Smarty PHP Templates

Tags: php, mobile, smarty, templating

I have a custom built app that uses smarty. I need my app to support mobile devices (iphones, driods etc...) I know that the general web looks ok, and that also in many cases I can use CSS hacks, but is there a way in Smarty to detect what browser is being used then serve up templates based on that request?

One type of template for:
-Desktops and Laptops
Another for 
-Smart Phones

Answer (score 1):

You can use plain PHP in Smarty:

```
{php}
if (preg_match('/iphone/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
   // iphone
} else if (preg_match('/android/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
   // android
} // and so on...
{/php}
```

Alternatively, you can create a Smarty plugin. I recall it is something like this:

```
function smarty_function_useragent_match($params, $template) {
    return preg_match($params['pattern'], $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
}
```

Look for more information on [Writing plugins](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/plugins.writing.tpl) on the Smarty site.

Answer (score 0):

way more better, would be to load the set of templates based on the user agent / device, so for example:

```
$template_dir = '/path/to/default/templates/';
if($mobile_device) {
    $template_dir = '/path/to/default/templates/';
}
```

or more dynamic like this:

```
$template_dir = '/path/to/templates/' . $device;
```

how granular $device here can be, depends on the application needs.

Answer (score 0):

Plain PHP is deprecated in Smarty 3, don't use it!

You can use a library, such as [Mobile Detect](http://mobiledetect.net/) or [Detect Mobile Browsers](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/).

Create a plugin in `plugins` directory, `function.detect_mobile.php`:

```
function smarty_function_detect_mobile($params, &$smarty) {

require_once './libraries/Mobile_Detect.php';
$detect=new Mobile_Detect;

$smarty->assign('is_mobile', false);
if($detect->isMobile()) {
    $smarty->assign('is_mobile', true);
}
}
```

Then use it in the template file:

```
{detect_mobile}
{if $is_mobile} 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles-mobile.css" type="text/css" />
{else}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" type="text/css" /> 
{/if}
```